# removing implicit conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, casting, implicit-conversion

I am attempting to eliminate an implicit conversion from the database.

I added the CAST statement below on the UpdatedByID field as this was a Char(10), it is joining to an INT in the FROM statement. But i'm still getting the Implicit conversions. I must be missing something obvious ??

```
        SELECT DISTINCT ba.BookingID INTO #temp1
        FROM BookedItemsAudit_tbl bia  
        INNER JOIN BookingAudit_tbl ba ON bia.BookingAuditID = ba.BookingAuditID    
        INNER JOIN User_tbl u ON  u.UserId  = CAST(ba.UpdatedById AS INT)
        WHERE bia.BookedItemTypeId IN (1, 58, 60)   
        AND u.UserId = 5
```

here is the cut down schema

```
BOOKINGAUDIT_TBL
Column_name     Type        Length
BookingAuditID  int         4
BookingID       int         4
UpdatedByID     CHAR        10
UpdatedBy       varchar     50
UpdatedDate     datetime    8
TotalMargin     money       8
BookingStatusId int         4

 USER_TBL
 Column_name    Type        Length
 UserId         int         4
 FullName       varchar     100
 UserName       varchar     20
```

full query and schema in this link

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ca48/1)

attached is the error message when the hint appears in the execution plan

[image: Implicit conversion after casting to INT]

Comment: You need to post the schema of your tables and also the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: To make your question more accessible, link to an example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some data that results in a failure.

Comment: Can we also see the schema of BookedItemsAudit_tbl

Comment: @tass thanks for the SQL fiddle link. I have never used that site before, looks very useful and intuitive

Comment: @robinDay Hi Robin, thought I'd post the lot to SQL fiddle in case I missed anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is about your *explicit* conversion not an *implicit* conversion. The tooltip you show doesn't mention `CONVERT_IMPLICIT`

`CAST(ba.UpdatedById AS INT)` shows up in the plan as `CONVERT(int,ba.UpdatedById ,0)` and it is warning you about that (it prevents an index seek on ba.UpdatedById).

To stop seeing this warning you would need to fix your schema so you are joining on columns of the same datatype.

Comment: @ martin smith, ok thanks martin, jumped the gun and didn't read the error properly 2nd time round... didn't expect it to still produce an a warning after the explicit conversion.... changing the field is a little more tricky!

Comment: @DamagedGoods - The warning is to alert you that the explicit `CAST` is unsargable and prevents an index seek on `ba.UpdatedById`. By the way did you both downvote and accept this answer?

Comment: sincere apologies! I meant to upvote this answer, but now its locked in.. I will send an email to admin, or if you edit the answer very slightly I think I can change the vote

Comment: @DamagedGoods - Ah thanks. Thought that was odd! I've edited the answer now.